# How to fix this. Returning wrong number of list size

Tags: python, queue

This queue code must return the exact Head, Tail, and Size of the list. It returns the correct Head and Tail, but the incorrect size.

```
class Queue:
    '''
        >>> x=Queue()
        >>> x.isEmpty()
        True
        >>> x.dequeue()
        'Queue is empty'
        >>> x.enqueue(1)
        >>> x.enqueue(2)
        >>> x.enqueue(3)
        >>> x.dequeue()
        1
        >>> print(x)
        Head:Node(2)
        Tail:Node(3)
        Queue:2 3
    '''
    def __init__(self): 
        # You can add a count variable
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    def __str__(self):
        temp=self.head
        out=[]
        while temp:
            out.append(str(temp.value))
            temp=temp.next
        out=' '.join(out)
        return ('Head:{}\nTail:{}\nQueue:{}'.format(self.head,self.tail,out))

    __repr__=__str__

    def isEmpty(self):
        #write your code here
        if self.head == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __len__(self):
        #write your code here
        node_count = 1
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node != None:
            current_node = current_node.next
            node_count += 1
            return node_count
        else:
            return node_count

    def enqueue(self, value):
        #write your code here
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node



    def dequeue(self):
        #write your code here
        if self.isEmpty():
            return 'Queue is empty'
        else:
            old_top_node = self.head
            new_top_node = self.head.next
            self.head = new_top_node
            return old_top_node.value
```

Expected: [12, 8, 11, 5], head=12, tail=5 and size 4

Actual Output: [12, 8, 11, 5], head=12, tail=5 and size 2

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where have you narrowed the problem down to? Starting `node_count` at 1 seems wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this is your issue the promblem stems from first you starting node_count at 1 due to this if there is no node then you will end up with a count of 1 still even though it should be 0. The other thing is your using a return which will exit the function completely. Instead, use continue which will just iterate to back to the top of the loop and after just return the node_count if there are no nodes it will skip the loop and return 0 else it will return the size you are looking for

```
 def __len__(self):
            node_count = 0
            current_node = self.head
            while current_node != None:
                current_node = current_node.next
                node_count += 1
                contuine
            return node_count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check out your definition of the `__len__(self)` method:

```py
   def __len__(self):
        #write your code here
        node_count = 1
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node != None:
            current_node = current_node.next
            node_count += 1
            # --- HERE ---
            return node_count
        else:
            return node_count
```

You are returning the value during the first iteration, so it will always be 2 (or 1 if `current_node` is `None`)